# Viewing webisite on Iphone

Tags: iphone, web

On iphone my website is not displaying properly. The content is cut almost at the end.

I thought

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

is causing the problem, but when I removed it the webiste was no longer mobile friendly.

How to solve this problem?

[Example photo - There should be contact details below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rhgub.jpg)

Comment: Scroll down? You know, it's very difficult to figure out what's going on here just by looking at a screenshot.

Comment: Please provide some code

Comment: Link to website: [link](http://www.advancedassistance.com.au/)